# Get URL of current page using php and ssi

Tags: php, html, apache, ssi

So I got a webpage written in HTML. Menu, Header and Footer are included using SSI (server side includes; .shtml). The website is running on an Apache server.
Now I want to build a language changer that changes the page from `[server]/de/index` to `[server]/en/index` in case you change the language from German to English.

Therefore I want to include this into the header. I already found out, that using PHP for getting the current URL is the best way to do it and within the `index.html` file for example the code is working.
But when I include the code into the SSI, it is returning nothing.

Any clues?

PHP-Code:

```
<?php
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $url;
?>
```

Index.html:

```
<body>
<!--#include file="res/Common/header.shtml" -->
<nav>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<!--#include file="res/Common/menu.shtml" -->
</div>
</nav>

<!--#include file="res/Common/footer.shtml" -->
</body>
</html>
```

header.shtml:

```
<div align="right"><p style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px"><font size="2">Language Selector</font></p></div>
```

Comment: Does the path to header/menu/footer change because of the language path? So, is res/Common/ the same no matter the language?

Comment: No, for each language there is one /common/ folder (because in SSIs it's somehow not allowed to use a parent folder)